# Determine the busiest time

Tags: code-golf, date

This challenge was greatly inspired by [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831137/how-to-determine-the-most-busy-period-of-time).

## Challenge

Given a bunch of clients in terms of when they enter a room and when they exit it, determine the period(s) of time when the room has a maximum number of people. The time resolution should be to the minute.

For example, if there are three clients `8 - 10`, `9 - 11`, `10 - 12`, then the correct answer would be `9 - 11`; during this time period, there are two clients in the room, which is the largest possible.

## Input

Input will be a list of pairs in some form. That can be either a list of 2-tuples, an even-length list with elements interleaved, etc, any reasonable input format. The times can be given in any reasonable format, in either 12- or 24- hour time. You may also input time as the number of minutes past midnight.

## Output

Output should be a list of pairs in some form, but the output is stricter. The output cannot be a flat list, it must be a list of 2-tuples or a list of lists, etc. The times can be output in any reasonable format, in either 12- or 24- hour time. You may also output time as the number of minutes past midnight.

## Examples

```
input
output

INPUT
08:00 - 10:00
09:00 - 11:00
10:00 - 12:00
OUTPUT
09:00 - 11:00

INPUT
08:20 - 09:20
09:00 - 09:10
08:00 - 09:30
08:50 - 10:40
OUTPUT
09:00 - 09:10

INPUT
08:00 - 10:00
09:00 - 10:00
09:30 - 11:00
OUTPUT
09:30 - 10:00 # The output is not always in the input list

INPUT
00:00 - 02:00
01:00 - 03:00
04:00 - 06:00
05:00 - 07:00
OUTPUT # This is the expected output for when there are multiple time ranges with the same "business".
01:00 - 02:00
05:00 - 06:00
```

You may assume that the second time in a pair will always be after the first time. Time ranges will not run over midnight.

Comment: What if there are multiple time ranges?

Comment: @Challenger5 What do you mean by multiple time ranges, Input or output?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Output.

Comment: @Challenger5 Added a test case, thanks.

Comment: Is `09:00 - 10:00, 10:00 - 11:00` a valid output for the first test case?

Comment: @LeakyNun I will say no; consecutive ranges need to be combined together.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 25 bytes

```
⟦₂ᵐkᵐcoḅlᵒlᵍthᵐ~c{~k~⟦₂}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rJHTU0Pt07IBuLk/Ic7WnMebp0ExL0lGUCRuuTquuw6iKJaIP///@hoAx0jA4NYnWhDAwMdYzDLBMgyA7NMgSxzICv2fxQA)

There's an obvious structure to this answer, which becomes even more obvious if you write it like this:

```
{⟦₂k}ᵐc oḅ lᵒlᵍ thᵐ ~c{~k~⟦₂}ᵐ
```

Unfortunately, Brachylog's evaluation order makes it so that the program goes into an infinite loop if you try to take advantage of the structure in question. Still, it's certainly possible to imagine a Brachylog-like language in which this is much shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
r/€Ṗ€F©®ċ$ÐṀQœ^‘$Ṣs2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1@k/6hpzcOd04Ck26GVh9Yd6VY5POHhzobAo5PjHjXMUHm4c1Gx0f/D7UD5o5Me7pwBpCP//4/m4oyONrEw0DEzMIjViTY1AbLMQCwgX8fcyCA2VgekwkBHwQikQCHaECiuYAxhm4DYZhC2KYhtDmTHcsUCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 58 bytes

```
⟦₂ᵐkᵐcoḅBlᵐ⌉;B↔z{hl~t?}ˢhᵐhᵐ{∋+₁.¬∈?∧|∋.-₁¬∈?∧}ᶠo~c.{l2}ᵐ∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rJHTU0Pt07IBuLk/Ic7Wp1ygKxHPZ3WTo/aplRVZ@TUldjXnl6UARQF4epHHd3aj5oa9Q6tedTRYf@oY3kNUERPFygEF6l9uG1Bfl2yXnWOUS3IsI7l//9HRxvoKBgZGMTqKEQbGgDZxhC2CYhtBmGbgtjmQHbs/ygA)

This has to be the longest Brachylog answer ever...

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>33</s> 24 bytes

```
JsrMQcSs-M_BhMBS{.M/JZJ2
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JsrMQcSs-M_BhMBS%7B.M%2FJZJ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B480%2C600%5D%2C%5B540%2C660%5D%2C%5B600%2C720%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C+200%5D%2C+%5B100%2C+300%5D%2C+%5B400%2C+600%5D%2C+%5B500%2C+700%5D%5D&debug=0)

Comment: This appears to behave incorrectly for [this](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JsrMQKS%7B.M%2FJZJm%2ChdhedcKx0qR1.%2BK&input=%5B%5B0%2C+200%5D%2C+%5B100%2C+300%5D%2C+%5B400%2C+600%5D%2C+%5B500%2C+700%5D%5D&debug=0). I will add this as a test case into the question as well.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino fixed.

Comment: Well, that was a fast answer. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 104 bytes

```
Reduce[#==#~MaxValue~x,x]&@PiecewiseExpand@Tr[Piecewise@{{1,#<=x<#2}}&@@@#]/.{Or->List,a_<=x<b_->{a,b}}&
```

Of course, this assumes that several high-power Mathematica built-ins are correct...